# How to patch value in p-dropdown using formcontrol if we want to specific data of user?

Tags: angular, dropdown, angular-reactive-forms, patch

```
<p-dropdown inputId="customerType" [options]="custTypeData" placeholder="Select" formControlName="customerType"
                        optionLabel="name"></p-dropdown>

   this.manageCustomerForm.patchValue({ 'customerType': this.dataSource.customerType });
```

Here from backend i am getting data of particular customer and now i want to show that particular value in dropdown as fixed.
At the time of search single json came and in that customer type also there.

Comment: So you want the user not to have an option? Like read only?

Comment: No, I am searching a particular customer by his id , so when i want to save new customer i need dropdown values but when i am searching i want single value of customer type that is coming from database.